# Method with Type (x) parameter returning Type x

Tags: c#

im a bit stuck right now and i hope u can quickstart me.

i Want a Method that i can for Example call like this:

```
string myString = GetSomething(typeof(string));
```

OR

```
DateTime dt = GetSomething(typeof(DateTime));
```

while `GetSomething` always returns the Type i give in as Argument. 
Is it possible to make this kind of signature? Or do i blow my head up for nothing right now?

Im atm stuck with this approach:

```
 public T GetSomething<T>(Type t ) where T : struct
```

Comment: You want it to return a new instance of the type you pass in?

Comment: As long as the object has a default constructor. Seems like the basic factory pattern would be a better candidate here.

Comment: @DoctorMick to be honest i don't get your Question. I want it to return a variable of the given type, so i can use it as i do in the above 2 Examples.

Comment: No, not like this. Why are you asking? How will you use this method? If you have a static `Type`, it is redundant - you can specify `<T>`. If you have a dynamic `Type`, you aren't using it in source code anyway (as the type of `dt` or `myString`) - so either way it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: default(T) return the default value for type T. It has the wanted signature

Comment: @Kobi yes i flattened that example a bit too much. 

It is for use as an Extension Method, and while i dont want to make x Extensions like GetSomethingDT, GetSomethingString etc. i want to pass over the type. I need the type because depending on it the routine will be different in a slight way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I've read your question correctly, all you should need is:

```
public T GetSomething<T> {
  return default(T);
}

DateTime dt = GetSomething<DateTime>();
```